# Adding multiple files to wordpress svn

Tags: svn, addition

Is their a way to add all files that arent present with svn example.

If i try to run

```
svn add *
```

i get this error

```
svn: warning: 'css' is already under version control
svn: warning: 'images' is already under version control
svn: warning: 'js' is already under version control
svn: warning: 'readme.txt' is already under version control
svn: warning: 's3audible.php' is already under version control
svn: warning: 'skin' is already under version control
```

so this means i have to add all new files individually i.e

```
test:trunk sam$ svn add js/colorpicker.js
A         js/colorpicker.js
test:trunk sam$ svn add js/layout.js
A         js/layout.js
test:trunk sam$ svn add css/colorpicker.css 
A         css/colorpicker.css
test:trunk sam$ svn add css/layout.css 
A         css/layout.css
```

etc etc

I want to just add all

any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try with --force option. Passing the --force option makes svn add recurse into versioned directories:

```
svn add * -–force
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

You can add more than one at once e.g. `svn add js/colorpicker.js js/layout.js` or `svn add js/* css/*` but I don't think there's an easy way to just add all missing files. You could hack one together using `svn status`, e.g.

```
svn status |sed -ne "s/^\?//p"
```

should print a list of changed files, then

```
svn add `svn status |sed -ne "s/^\?//p"`
```

should add them.

Answer (score 0):

Well i use simple way when i really want to commit/add multiple files in a min.

> svn st

which will list all the changed files

**M**       Source/Controllers/file1

**M**       Source/Controllers/file2

**M**       file3

then i copy the whole output and paste into vim editor

then  key to bring in visual mode
press 'g' two times 'gg' which will bring your cursor to the beginning of the file.
and the press  which will take you in to visual block and press  and make selection till which you want to cut using

and press  and then  to make selection of all text and then , now you are set because it bring multiple line into a single line, then you can copy this line to your terminal with

svn ci Source/Controllers/file1 Source/Controllers/file2 file3.

[image]

**Once you are habitual of this, i will ensure you will love it.** and whatever file you do not want to commit just delete that line by using 'dd'.